# Structural 2-1 mux fails during elaboration

Tags: verilog

So I'm trying to write a simple 2-1 mux in Verilog using logic gates and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The code for the mux is as follows:

```
module MUX_2_1 (i0 ,i1, sel ,o);
    input [31:0] i0, i1;
    input sel;
    output [31:0] o;

    wire [31:0] a, b;

    and #(8) and1(a, {32{sel}}, i0);
    and #(8) and2(b, {32{~sel}}, i1);
    or  #(8)  or1(o, a, b);
endmodule
```

The module compiles ok, but when I elaborate my test bench I get several errors (one for each gate) that take the form of

> gate (and1) has illegal output specification.

I understand how to make write the same mux using data flow, but I'm curious what the actual problem is here. I can't find anything online that suggests that the above code shouldn't work.

For reference, here is my test bench code:

```
module test_bench;
    reg [31:0] I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7;
    reg [2:0] SEL;
    wire [31:0] O8;

    //MUX_8_1 mux(I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, SEL, O8);
    MUX_2_1 mux(I0, I1, SEL[0], O8);

    initial
        begin
            I0 = 1;
            I1 = 2;
            I2 = 4;
            I3 = 8;
            I4 = 16;
            I5 = 32;
            I6 = 64;
            I7 = 128;

            SEL = 3'b000;
            #50 $display("SEL = %u, O8 = %u\n", SEL, O8);
            SEL = 3'b001;
            #50 $display("SEL = %u, O8 = %u\n", SEL, O8);
            SEL = 3'b010;
            #50 $display("SEL = %u, O8 = %u\n", SEL, O8);
            SEL = 3'b011;
            #50 $display("SEL = %u, O8 = %u\n", SEL, O8);
            SEL = 3'b111;
            #50 $display("SEL = %u, O8 = %u\n", SEL, O8);
            SEL = 3'b110;
            #50 $display("SEL = %u, O8 = %u\n", SEL, O8);
            SEL = 3'b100;
            #50 $display("SEL = %u, O8 = %u\n", SEL, O8);
            SEL = 3'b101;
            #50 $display("SEL = %u, O8 = %u\n", SEL, O8);
        end
endmodule
```

Comment: Well, that seems obvious in hindsight. Followup question, is there a good Verilog reference that I could have used to find this answer?

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is that you have **overridden the parameter** of the module (primitive in your case).

**To assign the delay of the gate, it is just `#<delay_value>` used.** So you instantiation may look like this:

```
and #8 and1...;
and #8 and2...;
or  #8 or1...;
```

Paremeter is a very different thing altogether.

> A parameter is defined by Verilog as a constant value declared within
>   the module structure. The value can be used to define a set of
>   attributes for the module which can characterize its behavior as well
>   as its physical representation

Suppose you want to make a verilog code, robust for the number of nets or configurable, then you can use the parameters.

For example :

```
module x (a, b);
  input [SIZE-1:0] a;
  output [SIZE-1:0] b;

  parameter SIZE = 4;

  // Your actual Verilog code
endmodule
```

So this code, by default generate `a[3:0], b[3:0]`. But since, it is parameterised by the `SIZE` value. One can override the `SIZE` value to get different number of nets.

**And to override the parameter value, you can use `#(<Paramter 1 Value>, <Parameter 2 Value>, ..., <Parameter n Value>)`.**

So if you instantiate module x, with SIZE = 6, then you should write like below:

```
x x1 #(6) (a, b); // Here SIZE = 6, and so 1[5:0], b[5:0]
```

Hope you have understood the difference.